# How does gravity work on the DeathStar?

Tags: star-wars, death-star, artificial-gravity

The Death Star is spherical, and as big as a moon.

It has a gravity generator, but how does it work ?

Which one of the case below (Fig.1 or Fig.2) is the correct one ?

[image]